# Javascript - element.madeUpAttribute is the same as element.getAttribute('madeUpAttribute') in IE8-

Tags: javascript, html

If I put a made-up attribute on an element then `element.madeUpAttribute` should return false. (It does in modern browsers.)

However in IE8- it returns the attribute value, acting just like: `element.getAttribute('madeUpAttribute')`.

Any way to make it return the attribute value only if the attribute is supported by the browser?

Thanks guys!

### [update]

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/rWz2n/

This is what it looks like in IE8:

[http://f.cl.ly/items/0d1t3l2E1n1a3j0l1W2j/IE8.png](http://cl.ly/FsUf)

Comment: Actually `element.madeUpAttribute` should return `undefined`.

Comment: Why *should* it? Do you have a standards reference that says so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking, whether some feature is supported with `'madeUpAttribute' in element` does the trick in several cases for me.

Actaually you may try to check element's prototype.

There's no prototype for DOM objects in older IE, but there's one interesting [ancient feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb263996%28VS.85%29.aspx#dude1001_topic3)

```
if (element.prototype) {
  return 'madeUpAttribute' in element.prototype
} else {
  document.expando = false;
  var hasProp = true;
  try {
    element.madeUpAttribute = element.madeUpAttribute;
  } catch(e) {
    hasProp = false;
  }
  document.expando = true;
  return hasProp;
}
```

This will work for the first assignment, though. After property is set, it is considered, that it do exists.

Comment: What exact result do you want?

Comment: Wait I was wrong. It isn't working in IE8. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/rWz2n/ This is how it looks in IE8: http://cl.ly/FsUf

Comment: Updated my answer with some idea.